# "being one of the masses", or; "being one of the mass"

Tags: singular-vs-plural

Writing an English book as non native speaker leaves one suspended in mid-air on numerous issues. Should mass here be plural or singular?

> *being one of the masses*
>   *being one of the mass*

I've tried to Google it, but nothing useful popped up.

Comment: Interesting question, but methinks you selected the wrong answer. [Relevant meta post](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/not-so-fast-when-should-i-accept-my-answer).

Comment: Well, since they both point out the right choice, both are right. I found the one I accepted clearer for its brevity. Yet I can see why the other one is more favoured, since it is more generally oriented.

Comment: The currently-accepted answer was corrected _after_ you had already accepted it. Moreover, that answer might tell you which one to use, but I still think it as incorrect information in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When used as a noun, the plural, [the masses](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/masses) is the only option with this meaning, and it must be used with the definite article. The correct way of expressing this is

> being one of **the masses**

When used as an adjective, [mass](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/mass) has a related meaning

> having an effect on or involving a large number of people or forming a large amount

When used in the singular noun, [mass](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/mass) has several meanings, none of which are relevant to this meaning.

Answer (score -2):

When you say:

> A mass of the people were bothered.

It means a considerable number of people were bothered.
 On the other hand **the masses** refers to the people as a group (ie the common people). For example:

> This bothered the masses.

So you should say one of the masses.

Comment: A mass of the people were bothered ≠ a majority of people were bothered; a considerable amount ≠ a larger amount. The word _mass_ **can** refer to a majority, but it can also refer to some significant number smaller than that.

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you for the correction I have edited the answer.

Comment: I have edited your edit. See [this Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+number+of+people%2C+an+amount+of+people&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15).

Comment: When used to mean **majority**, it must be used with the definite article, **the mass of**. http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/mass

Comment: @Panic: I think you'll find that we take answers pretty seriously here. :-)

Comment: But @javaLatte said that it was correct.

Comment: @Panic, if you read my comment carefully, it says that **the mass of** (note the definite article) has the meaning **majority**. You wrote **a mass of** (note the indefinite article),  Following the link that I provided, you will see that, when used **with the indefinite article** about people, it means **a large number of people crowded together**.